# I am new in programming, I am learning node.js but while doing parsedUrl I am getting [object:null] with the output, How to fix it

Tags: node.js, programming-languages

I do the below program run, sorry for my grammatical, My first language is not English, So if I am not descriptive forgive me and ask the question pls.
my output is
E:\Love>node punit.js
The server is listening on port 5000 now
Request received on path: fof with method: get and with these query string parameters [Object: null prototype] { fizz: 'buzz' }
My Code is Below

```js
/*
 * Primary file for API
 *
 */

// Dependencies
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');

 // Configure the server to respond to all requests with a string
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){

  // Parse the url
 var parsedUrl = url.parse(req.url, true);

  // Get the path
  var path = parsedUrl.pathname;
  var trimmedPath = path.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g, '');

  // Get the query string as an object
  var queryStringObject = parsedUrl.query;

  // Get the HTTP method
  var method = req.method.toLowerCase();

  // Send the response
  res.end('Hello World!\n');

  // Log the request/response
  console.log('Request received on path: '+trimmedPath+' with method: '+method+' and this query string: ',queryStringObject);
});

// Start the server
server.listen(3000,function(){
  console.log('The server is up and running now');
});
```

Actual output
E:\Love>node punit.js
The server is listening on port 5000 now
Request received on path: fof with method: get and with these query string parameters  { fizz: 'buzz' }

My code image is below

Comment: Paste the codes, instead of linking image, please

Comment: code snippet is added please have a look

Comment: so what's the error, you're getting object right? `{ fizz: 'buzz' }`

Comment: the error is [object: null prototype], this{[object: null prototype]} should not come along with the output the tutor told me that

Comment: I also have the same problem. if i do `console.log(parsedUrl)` it shows `parsedUrl.query: [Object: null prototype] { fizz: 'buzz' }` but in video it shows just `{ fizz: 'buzz' }`

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**

If second parameter is `true` here `url.parse(req.url, true)`, you can't get rid of `[Object: null prototype]` (looks like it's part of nodes inbuild functionality, probably as a reminder)

It's because you're setting `parseQueryString` parameter of `url.parse` to `true`. From the docs:

> If true, the query property will always be set to an object returned by the `querystring` module's `parse()` method.

From `querystring.parse` docs

> The object returned by the querystring.parse() method **does not prototypically inherit from the JavaScript Object**. This means that typical Object methods such as obj.toString(), obj.hasOwnProperty(), and others are not defined and will not work.

So on `console.log` it's always preceded with `[Object: null prototype]`, for example `query: [Object: null prototype] { q: 'ok' }`

I would assume it's there (as a part of nodes functionality) to remind that `prototype` of `query` object is `null`.

For instance, the same behaviour can be observed in the following:

```
const a = { b: 1 }
a.__proto__ = null; // <-- set prototype of a to null
console.log(a)
// outputs [Object: null prototype] { b: 1 }
```

Comment: can we use JSON.stringify(queryStringObject) to eliminate that error or does that cause any error or bug in my code

Comment: @PunitPal, in that case you're logging string **not** object

Comment: I just want to know, The above Code and output which I mention I copied from Udemy instructor and his output was perfect without [output:null prototype] how's that possible Can you give some logic behind that or any advice that you have and Thanks for above explanation Thank You very much

Comment: if i do console.log(parsedUrl) it shows parsedUrl.query: [Object: null prototype] { fizz: 'buzz' } but in video it shows just { fizz: 'buzz' }